# Omit topmost caller for error handler using confess/croak/cluck?

Tags: perl, exception

I wrote my own kind of exception handler used like `catch2 { some_code } [optional params]`.
It works, calling `confess` when the exception is not handled.
For simplicity I put it right into the package where it's needed.
However the top call frames include my `catch2` sub.

How can I omit that in an easy way?

It seems to me that neither of those can help as they refer to packages, not subs each:

```
@CARP_NOT
%Carp::Internal
%Carp::CarpInternal
```

`$Carp::CarpLevel=1` seems to do the trick, but the docs say it should not be used (perl 5.18.2).

Comment: Put your function in new/separate package.

Comment: @AnFi Actually not necessary. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To omit the call frames from the module where exception handling is implemented, use:

```
use Carp;
$Carp::Internal{(__PACKAGE__)} = 1;
```

You might be interested in Perl bug "#132281: Improve documentation on %Carp::Internal", too.

For my experimental exception handling package `ExES` being implemented in `ExES.pl` together with some test code (in package `main`) the difference is like this:

Default message:

```
catch(): Illegal division by zero at ExES.pl line 78.
 at ExES.pl line 36.
    ExES::catch(CODE(0x558a56b9cdb8), undef) called at ExES.pl line 48
    ExES::catch2(CODE(0x558a56b9cdb8)) called at ExES.pl line 78
```

With the solution applied, the output is:

```
catch(): Illegal division by zero at ExES.pl line 78.
 at ExES.pl line 78.
```